# C2DM limitation?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

As of 5/2011 the google [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#limitations) for c2dm says this:

"Google limits the number of messages a sender sends in aggregate, and the number of messages a sender sends to a specific device"

What is the specific limitation? If my server sends 10 messages a day to 10,000 devices will Google shut my app down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific limitation is derived per account and is modifiable upon (reasonable) request. For example, I have c2dm account which is "restricted" to "just" 100,000 c2dm messages per day.

Comment: How was the process of getting restricted account? Any cost with it?

Answer (score 2):

When you [signup C2DM here](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/android/c2dm/signup.html), you're asked to fill in a estimated "Estimated total number of messages per day" and "Estimated peak queries per second (QPS)". 
According the [C2DM quotas page](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/android/c2dm/quotas.html), the currently default limit is approximately ***200,000 messages per day***.

If your requirement exceeds this limit, you should make sure using C2DM correctly, and submit the request quotas at the bottom link of the [quotas page](http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/android/c2dm/quotas.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about message count limitation, you should switch to GCM anyways.

[There is only a limit of messages saved before collapsing, which is 100](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html).

C2DM is deprecated and has been replaced by [Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM)](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).
Google's statement:

```
Important: C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012.
This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota requests. 
No new features will be added to C2DM. However, apps using C2DM will continue to work. 
Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to migrate to the new version of C2DM, 
called Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM).
See the C2DM-to-GCM Migration document for more information.
Developers must use GCM for new development.
```

There is a [demo app tutorial for GCM](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html) and also for [migration](https://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html) from C2DM.